# Smooth line animation on map

Tags: openlayers, typescript, angular, animatedmarker

I tried to produce a smooth line animation with below code. How can I do this?

I used OpenLayers with Angular. It works as a drawing line but I want more smooth movement something like this (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html). I didn't modify my code because this example have JS but I am working on TS. Besides I used random data which is coming from Python client by websockets to node.js server.

I just want to flowing marker, but in my code marker has stopped and then appear again. I need consistent marker and it should not disappear.

map.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, SimpleChanges, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import * as ol from 'openlayers';
import { AppStateService } from '../state/appstate.service';
import { DataService } from 'src/core/data.service';
import {Subscription, timer} from 'rxjs';
const INITIAL_OPACITY = 1;
const DIMMED_OPACITY = 0.3;
var longval = 0;
var latval = 0;
@Component({
  selector: 'map',
  template: `<div id="map"></div>`,
  styleUrls: ['map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  private map: ol.Map;
  stockQuote: number;
  sub: Subscription;
  constructor(private appStateService: AppStateService, private dataService: DataService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM(),opacity: INITIAL_OPACITY }),
      ],
      target: document.getElementById('map'),
      view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326', // map type
        center: [32.7399307, 39.9066235],
        zoom: 6,
      })
    });
    this.appStateService.getDim().subscribe(
      x => {
        if (x) {
          this.map.getLayers().getArray()[0].setOpacity(INITIAL_OPACITY);
        } else {
          this.map.getLayers().getArray()[0].setOpacity(DIMMED_OPACITY);
        }
      }
    )
    this.sub = this.dataService.getQuotes()
      .subscribe(value => {
        var long = value['long'];
        var lat = value['lat'];
        if (longval === 0)
          longval = long;
        if (latval === 0)
          latval = lat;
        var source = new ol.source.Vector({});
        var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: source });
        this.map.addLayer(layer);
        var marker = new ol.Feature({
          zoom: 8,
          geometry: new ol.geom.LineString([[lat, long], [latval,longval]])
        });
         var marker2 = new ol.Feature({
          zoom: 8,
          //geometry: new ol.geom.Point([lot, lang]) // dont worry about coordinate type 0,0 will be in west coast of africa
          geometry: new ol.geom.Point([lat, long])
          //geometry: new ol.geom.LineString([[lat, long], [latval,longval]])
        });
        source.addFeature(marker)
        function delay(ms:number){
          return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) );
        }
        (async () => {
            // Do something before delay
            source.addFeature(marker2)
            await delay(500);
            // Do something after
          source.removeFeature(marker2)
        })();
        longval = long;
        latval = lat;
      });
  }
```

Comment: What does not work in the above code? Don't let people guess from your code what does not work. Why tag openlayers-2? Are you actually using this obsolete version?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: @TomazicM it works as a drawing line but ı want more smooth movement something like this ( https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html)  but ı didnt modify my code because this example have js but ı am working on ts , besides ı used random data which is coming from python client by websockets to node.js server. sorry ı am new and ı do not know somethings.

Comment: You didn't answer question about OpenLayers 2?

Comment: @TomazicM yes this not 2  ı used this https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext-angular

Comment: What is your definition of "smooth"? You have half a second delay in your marker display function.

Comment: @TomazicM ı just want to flowing marker , in my code marker has stopped and then appear again , ı need  consistent marker and it should not dissappear

Comment: Please edit your question and add all additional explanations from your comments to the body of the question so it might be opened again.

Comment: @TomazicM thank you I edited question

Comment: There are three more votes required to reopen the question or intervention of @Ian Turton. Then I can propose a solution.

Comment: @TomazicM okey ı hope you will help me

Comment: @Ian Turton Can you reopen this question?

Answer (score 1):

Your `marker2` blinks (disappears) because you are removing it by `source.removeFeature(marker2)` and then adding again by `source.addFeature(marker2)`.

Since it's the same marker that just changes position it's not necessary to remove it, just change coordinates of it's point geometry. First define marker outside data retrieval and display function `this.dataService.getQuotes()`. Since I'm not familiar with Angular environment, I don't know where is the right place to put it and how you then reference it.

Let's say you put declaration `var marker2;` at top level and then create marker, without adding it to source yet:

```
marker2 = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0, 0])
});
```

Then inside your `async` method just change/update marker coordinates and add marker to source if it's not added yet:

```
(async () => {
    marker2.getGeometry().setCoordinates([lat, long]);
    if (!source.hasFeature(marker2)) source.addFeature(marker2);
    await delay(500);
})();
```

Comment: First of all thank you for answering my question but ı did these and it gives some errors :    Error:(78, 26) TS2339: Property 'setCoordinates' does not exist on type 'Geometry'.Error:(79, 17) TS2551: Property 'hasFeature' does not exist on type 'Vector'. Did you mean 'addFeature'?   how can ı fix these with proper function

Comment: Since I don' see your code I can't say what's wrong. I tested the code in plain JS environment and it works.